# Having an issue with the browser clearing the information when code is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a problem with my browser apparently clearing the cache when using location.reload(); to try and reload the page for me when a change is made. So in my HTML I have this:

```
      <select id="country" onchange="reloadPage()">
      <option value="0" name="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="1" name="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
```

and then here is the Javascript code that I have in between the head tags:

```
<script>
function reloadPage()
 {
 location.reload();
 }
</script>
```

So the problem is that when I select "Other", the page reloads and "United States" is selected instead of "Other" and all the other information in the form is cleared out as well.  It seems to me that the browser isn't caching the change and so when it reloads it clears everything out.  Any information that was input into the form is cleared when the page reloads with this function.  Is there a way to correct this so that when the browser reloads through this function it won't reset the form to it's original state?

Comment: why are you reloading?

Comment: I am reloading because depending on what is selected I have certain input fields being activated / deactivated.  The page needs to reload because the function that activates / deactivates those fields runs when the page is loaded through the onload attribute.

Comment: input will not carry over a reload(). I suggest putting you activating/deactivating stuff into a function and just call that instead of reload.

Comment: Thanks, that works... not sure why I didn't think of that before.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments by [attila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3389631/attila), instead of reloading the page you can simply call a function to do your stuff.

However, my point here is that for keeping the state of the page after refreshing the page or even closing the browser, we can simply use `localStorage`.

Here is a simple example:

```
localStorage["selectedCountry"] = "US";  //store page data
//refresh page...
var country = localStorage["selectedCountry"]; //read page data. country is now "US"
```